# Resetting a password program in Java

Tags: java, passwords

Hi I am creating a resetPassword method in my SecretKeeper class.  It has to create a random password with length = to numLetters, and there are four boolean values that the password must have if true. How do I program the resetPassword method? Thanks!
Here is what I have:

```
public class SecretKeeper
{
private int     secretNumber;
private char    secretLetter;
private String  secretWord;
private String  password;

public SecretKeeper(){
    secretNumber = 131313;
    secretLetter = '@';
    secretWord = "c@T";
}

public boolean guessNumber(int guess){
    return guess == secretNumber;
}

public boolean guessLetter(int guess){
    return guess == secretLetter;
}

public boolean guessWord(String word){
    return word.equals(secretWord);
}

public void resetPassword(int numLetters, boolean hasLowerCase, boolean hasUpperCase, boolean hasSpecial, boolean hasNumbers){
     password = "";
     Random rnd = new Random();



}
```

}

Comment: Is the password related to the other fields (`secretNumber` etc) in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Use a known Hashing Algorithm eg sha512 to generate a hash string on a random number, then take the first letters according to the filters.

Eg. If you need only 4 uppercase and your hash string is: aD562Hvdt356H7Jss

your password would be : DHHJ

A simple solution that works!

If you require a longer password than there are letters in the hash string, create another hash string from another random number as you run out of letters!